# Background image in WPF button is displayed horizontaly flipped (like a mirror)

Tags: c#, wpf

When i set a background image for a WPF button - it appears as the opposite direction  - horizontal flipped (like a mirror).
Any solution?
(It does not have to do with the flowdirection)

```
 <Button x:Name="btnGoodMark" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Path=GoodBtnTxt}" Click="btnGoodMark_Click" FontSize="30">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource ="Images/Green_V.png"  ></ImageBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Maybe `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform`... you have to provide a verifyable example, otherwise its not easy to help.

Comment: Also it's not quite clear whether you look for a hint WHY it is flipped or a solution HOW TO revert the image to original direction.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it isn't clear why there should be any horizontal flipping of the image at all.

However, set the ImageBrush's `RelativeTransform` property to revert that effect:

```
<Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Green_V.png">
        <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" CenterX="0.5"/>
        </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
    </ImageBrush>
</Button.Background>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) Use ScaleTransform:

```
        <Button x:Name="btnGoodMark" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" Content="ABC" FontSize="30" >
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ></ScaleTransform>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
```

Comment: "Note that the converter is required". That's wrong. Set `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` Or set `LayoutTransform` instead `RenderTransform`, which compensates any translation. Note also that your solution would flip/mirror the whole Button, include the text in its Content.

Comment: Thanks, you are right,. Of course I think "-0.5,x" is correct (in which x can be any value).

Comment: "in which x can be any value", sure, `0.5` for instance. `-0.5` is wrong however. RenderTransformOrigin is given in relative units ranging from 0 to 1, `0.5,0.5` being the center of the element, independent of its actual size.

Comment: Ok. I checked it. _RenderTransformOrigin.X_ should be "0.5". _RenderTransformOrigin.Y_ is not important (The result is the same in this situation). However, these values can also be negative.

Comment: Sure they can, but for flipping horizontally *at the center*, the x value must be `0.5`, not `-0.5`.

Comment: Right. However, your answer is much clearer. thanks.